# How to Edit Android dialog heading

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Can I enter **two text rows** as the **Android dialog** heading. If so, how can I do that? I tried as,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog).setTitle(Heading)
```

and set the title using new line character as below.

```
Heading="raw 1 \n raw 2";
```

but it's not working and just show the "\n" in the heading. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
builder.setTitle("raw 1 \n raw 2");
```

And onother Solution i s

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);

textView.setText("raw 1 \n raw "2);

dialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(textView);
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works. I tried before. But didn't work. Now it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use Html.fromHtml() method to show html content on TextView

EX:

```
String Heading="raw 1 \n raw 2";

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(Heading));

dialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string to declare :  `<string name="text">row1\nrow2</string>`

```
builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.text));
```